# Can a Perl BEGIN block spread a virus or lose data?

Tags: perl, compilation

I am still new to Perl. Since `BEGIN` blocks are run during compilation can't a virus spread or data loss occur from simply compiling? Does Perl do anything to stop it? If so does it mean the code in `BEGIN` blocks may act differently outside of it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes to all these questions.  The Eclipse IDE was vulnerable to this.  It [discussed in more detail here](http://twoalpha.blogspot.com/2006/03/perl-begin-blocks-considered-harmful.html).

As with all software, you should avoid downloading and running anything from a source you do not trust.  CPAN is generally trustworthy; although I am not aware of anyone intentionally releasing rogue code to CPAN, it's possible it has happened.

You can avoid running code during compile checks with the [$^C flag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5eC), e.g.:

```
BEGIN { load_data_from_db() unless $^C; }
```

Comment: Excellent point about `$^C`. Here's a link to the perlvar entry for it: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$^C

Comment: @daotoad your link was broken, so I edited the response to contain a working one.

Answer (score 2):

chromatic explains [how a Perl program works](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/how-a-perl-5-program-works.html).

Answer (score 1):

Note that sometimes this is a feature.  BEGIN blocks inside mod_perl modules are executed only once, when they are first loaded.  So you have a simple syntax to do page-level initialization in the same script, and place it "near" the code that it assists.

Occasionally it's similarly useful for writing complicated initialization code that you don't want to put at the top of a script.

But mostly it's just there for thematic compatibility with awk.

Comment: It's there for a lot more than looking like awk. BEGIN blocks are very useful for sequencing things.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I said?  There was quite a bit of text before the sentence you decided to pick on..

Comment: @Andy - you said "mostly". In my many years of Perl software development, I have used (and seen it used) BEGIN blocks for a number of reasons on miriad of occasions, and not ONCE have I seen it used "thematic compatibility with awk".